# Bypassing a 2FA login to access a Bearer token using Python requests/selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, python-requests

I am currently trying to setup a python program which would periodically check for changes in .json data from a GET request to a private API. In order to send this request, I need a valid Bearer token. I have no problems once I have a valid token, but they expire within a couple hours, which doesn't fit my program's needs. The only feasible way I see to access this token is through a manual/automated login to the website that accesses the token, then uses it to send a request for the .json data.

I'm able to submit credentials, however the website requests 2FA through text, which then allows for a (seemingly) infinite amounts of logins that don't require 2FA. I have tried extracting and importing cookies to bypass the 2FA, which I thought would work, but didn't. I am wondering if it is even possible to bypass the 2FA in order to obtain a Bearer token for my request automatically.

**What I know**
The website uses OAuth v2
The website requires a valid Bearer token to send a request to the API

**What I want to do**
Periodically access data via a GET request to a private API

Comment: Please show us what you have tried already and where you are stuck exactly!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.